# Boolean statement not evaluating in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a script, and there are two boolean statements that are very similar but giving different results, and I don't see why they conflict with one another.

My function looks like this:

**SCRIPT:**

```
(function() {
    window.onload = function() {
        let stopped = true;
        let button = document.getElementById("start-stop");

        if (stopped) {
           setInterval(function() {
               console.log("The timer is working.");
           }, 1000);
        }

        button.addEventListener('click', function(){
            if (stopped) {
                stopped = false;
                console.log(stopped);
            }  else {
                stopped = true;
                console.log(stopped);
            }
       });
   }
}
}).call(this);
```

The basic idea is that when I push the button the `setInterval` function stops, however it keeps on going even when the `if/else` function switches stopped to `false`.

For example, my console.log looks like this:

[image: console log when my function is run.]

I.e. `stopped = false`, but setInterval doesn't terminate.

Why is this not evaluating correctly?

Comment: `stopped` becoming false does not stop the `setInterval`. For that, you'd have to use `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to work on a piece of code that has already started to operate. In simpler words, the setInterval method will be called every 1000ms, no matter what the value of stopped variable is. If you wish to really stop the log, you can do any of these:

```
clearInterval()
```

to completely remove the interval or

```
       setInterval(function() {
          if (stopped) {
            console.log("The timer is working.");
          }
       }, 1000);
```

to check if the value of stopped variable has changed or not (after the click) and act accordingly. Choose either of these for your purpose..

Answer (score 2):

you are calling setinterval even before button is clicked .As the event is already triggered you cannot stop just by setting the variable to false ,you need to clear the interval using clearinterval

check the following snippet

```js
var intervalId;
window.onload = function() {
  let stopped = true;
  let button = document.getElementById("start-stop");
  var Interval_id;
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (stopped) {
      Interval_id = callTimeout();

      stopped = false;

    } else {

      clearInterval(Interval_id);
      stopped = true;
    }
  });
}

function callTimeout() {
  intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("The timer is working.");
  }, 1000);
  return intervalId;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="start-stop" value="click it">
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Put the `if(stopped)` statement inside the `setInterval` function because if you used this function once it will keep going..

Another way to stop `setInterval` function is by using `clearInterval`, like this

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() { /* code here */}, 1000)
// And whenever you want to stop it
clearInterval(intervalId);
```

Comment: Similar answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button stopped variable becomes false but the setInterval will not stop because the setInterval code is already executed.. it will not execute again on button click. And if you reload the page what will happen is that stopped variable will be again set to true as you have written at first line and setInterval will execute again ..

Now What you can do is store setInterval in a variable like this

```
var timer = setInterval(function,1000);
```

and then when you click the button use this method to clear interval

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

this should do the trick .. Hope it helps ..